# Bad url test cases

Tags: unit-testing, url, testcase

I'm working on a function to validate http urls. I need some good and bad urls to do unit testing. Please share me your test cases.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many permutations and combinations ... also how strictly you are conforming to the standard spec is something to worry about

What are the protocols supported ... is it only http ... or https, rmtp etc as well

Consider things like domains and subdomains ... www.google.com and www.maps.google.com are valid

Presence or absence of trailing slash

Non-standard port ... http://www.example.com:8800

Deep path after the host ... http://www.example.com/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/i.html

URL Parameters ... http://www.test.com?pageid=123&testid=1524

URL encoding ... and how are URL are encoded within a URL if they are the part of the parameters

Anchor tags ... http://www.test.com/do.html#A

Presence of special characters ... if any

handling white spaces

Max and Min size of a URL

Interesting!!

Have you investigated in existing libraries which let you validate the URLs

Answer (score 1):

I would take a look at [RFC1738](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt) to find the test cases. For example start wible the schema *wibble* (i.e. wibble://www.bbc.co.uk). This should be invalid.

Answer (score 1):

Define 'bad'?

Characters that should have been escaped?

```
http://stackoverflow.com/users/9999999/not a-real-user
```

Accidentally transposed characters?

```
http//:stackoverflow.com/questions/9715606/bad-url-test-cases
```

URLs that just result in a 404?

```
http://stackoverflow.com/users/9999999/not-a-real-user
```